# How to call an external js file <script src="path_to_file/file_name.js"> for screen size less than 768px?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a file with php Yii code, designed using bootstrap. In that, I require a particular external js file only for screen width 768px or less. How can I call the external js file  for screen size less than 768px?

I have tried:
    `<div class="show-xs"> <script src="path_to_file/file_name.js"> </div>`
Where the div is styled "display:none" upto 768px and "display:block" below 768px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Verified and working!**

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width < 768) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_file/file_name.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```